# Fat aar does not include modules resources in Android

Tags: android, android-drawable, aar, fatjar

I want to generate a fat-aar of an app module and use it as a dependency in another app.

I have used [this](https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android) library to generate the fat-aar.

I have an app module which is converted as a library module and a feature module called splash and Splash module is included in the app module.

With the help of above library I have successfully generated the fat-aar, but this fat-aar doesnot include the drawable resources of Splash module which crashes the app at run time with below exception.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field ic_app_splash of type I in class 
Lcom/app/passenger/R$drawable; or its superclasses
```

This ic_app_splash is present inside the splash module.

Please provide the solution as why the fat-aar is not including the resources of a module.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that is [Issue 406](https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android/issues/406). Reading the associated issues your problem might be solved with the [answer to Issue 19](https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android/issues/19#issuecomment-509225017) and the [corresponding explanation by the lib's dev](https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android/issues/19#issuecomment-512156676) which, in short, is:

> The support lib version that your application uses is best to be the same as the library uses.

Note, that the developer also states:

> I am no longer engaged in research and development, so the project will not be updated and maintained.

However you can also use the probably more common way, and either create AARs [with Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) or via CLI [with AAPT](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2).